# Scala - passing a function - a type mess

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following code in Scala-IDE:

```
type myF = () => Boolean

def acceptFunction(f: myF) {
  //...
}
```

and then:

```
var a = false

def isA = () => a
```

but when I try passing it, to the acceptFunction, it results in error:

```
acceptFunction(isA)
```

the error is:

> type mismatch; found : () => Boolean required: Boolean

But why?

If I declare `isA` like this:

```
def isA() = () => a
```

then it is accepted, but I assume, it get's evaluated because of the parenthesis.

Is there any way to pass such a function for furhter evaluation?

**UPDATE:**

Looks like it is something with Scala-IDE. The REPL has no problems with these expressions. However, still I can't make it so that the passed function does not get turned into a closure. I mean, that it turns into closure, and changing the `var a` later and calling the example with `println(f())` again - does not change the value. So, the second part of the question remains - is there any way to pass such a function for furhter evaluation?

Comment: I updated my answer with more questions in response to your update.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in Scala IDE. I wrapped your code inside an `object`.

Comment: It does fail with the error you mention if I add the empty parenthesis at the call site, like so `acceptFunction(isA())` -- which of course is correct, since when you apply the function you get back a `Boolean`.

Comment: I do get your error when I try to call `acceptFunction(isA _)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't make a mistake when writing your code the first time?  I copied and pasted what you had into the 2.9.1 REPL and it worked fine.

```
scala> type myF = () => Boolean
defined type alias myF

scala>  var a = false
a: Boolean = false

scala> def isA = () => a
isA: () => Boolean

scala> def acceptFunction(f: myF) {println(f())}
acceptFunction: (f: () => Boolean)Unit

scala> acceptFunction(isA)
false

scala>
```

**UPDATE:**  `isA` is a closure when you define it.  Passing it to `acceptFunction` has no effect on whether it grabs `a`.

Is your purpose to write a function, `acceptFunction`, which takes a function, `f`, which captures an external value, `a`, at the time it's defined?

You could do that like so:

```
// Defines a function which returns a function with returns the 
// value that was captured at the outer function's call time.
def isB = { (b: Boolean) => { () => b }: myF }

a = true

val f = isB(a)

acceptFunction(f) // >> true

a = false

acceptFunction(f) // >> true
```

Is that where you're trying to go?

Comment: Same here, I was writing the same answer.

Comment: Same here with Scala version 2.9.1-1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_31).

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Seems like it is something with Scala-IDE. This is not first time that it seems what's not there. Yes, it worked for me in the REPL too. However, it always generates a closure, so that changin the var later has no effect on the passed function. See the question update.